# Is there a way to see in the editor, if a class is into any one of the point-cuts using annotations?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, spring-aop

Is there a plugin or editor feature, to see if any of the methods in the class belong to a particular point-cut.

Answer (score 2):

The AJDT support such decorators [(example)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ajdt/advisedByMenu.GIF)

Comment: Can we use this for Spring, where we define aop on xml.